# GhostBin Exception: The remote server returned an error: (406) Not Acceptable

Tags: c#, webclient

Aight, before I get redirected to some post that doesn't answer this. I would like to state that I am creating a program AUTO UPDATER. And how it works is that if it sees 1.0.0.0 then fine, 1.0.0.1 then update.

So I went to Ghostbin, a site that allows you to change text on there and I linked it up to my code. Thing is, it gave me this error. I don't know how to fix it.

> Exception: The remote server returned an error: (406) Not Acceptable

Here is my code.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!new WebClient().DownloadString("https://ghostbin.com/paste/odmbf")
                        .Contains("1.0.0.0"))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You are running the latest version!", "No Update",
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
    else
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("New Update! Would you like to update?", "Yay!", 
            MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information) == 
            System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            Process.Start("...");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try commenting out the line where you add the header...

Comment: done. no fix :0

Comment: Did you notice the header was added to `client`, where your `WebClient` is `wc`? Does your program add the header to the correct instance (`wc`)?

Comment: Let me change the code in the description so it is simpler and avoids that

Comment: That doesn't work and same error. Now what? I removed those variables.

Comment: The issue is probably some protection on the website from naïve scraping. The best chance of fixing it would be to look at the request by your browser in something like Fiddler and attempting to replicate that, including all the headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ghostbin doesn't seem to accept the WebClient.

Fake it to appear as a browser using

```
wc.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36");
```

Comment: Careful though. While Ghostbin doesn't appear to have any ToS disallowing this, the intent is clear, and unless you manage to fake a browser perfectly, they may make changes in the future to block this again.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. Use pastebin instead. they have an edit option where you can edit a raw file!

Comment: When the service you're using doesn't allow what you want to do, switching to a different service that does allow it is exactly the right thing to do, so yeah, go with this. Plenty of other free services out there would also allow it.